# Not working for node reference with more than two levels

Tags: 6, nodes

Please help. I am able to make it work using taxonomy heirarchy but not using node reference. I would prefer node reference as you can add extra fields to these items like description, geo points etc..

Here is my set up:

[ City -> Developments -> Projects ]

e.g.:
(city) (development) (project)
Dubai -> Arabian Ranches Development -> Al Reem Project

And lots of cities that relates to their own set of developments -> again with their own sets of projects.

Development Node contains node reference to City (not heirarchical)
Project Node contains node reference to Development (not heirarchical)
and finally,
Property Item Node which contains the heirarchical node reference to Development, but when I reference it to 'Project' (which should be the case) it disappears upon selecting it!

I do not know what is wrong please help!